# Which is the better way to store my logincredentials(remember me option) and maintain session throughout the application in angular js

Tags: angularjs, session, cookies, authentication

Iam developing angular js web application .I want to store the login credentials when the user checks on remember me option.can any one please suggest me which is the better way to store the details of user (local storage or cookies or etc).And I want to maintain the session throughout the application ..please give your suggestions.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are already plenty of solutions for that kind of stuff. As this is a serious security issue, I would recommend to use one of those instead of *"reinventing the wheel"*.

Whether the system is using cookies or localstorage doesn't really matter at the end of the day. It is however a bad idea in general to store the actual credentials. Instead, use a token-based system that will do a server-client handshake on request.

Personally, I am working with [Firebase](http://firebase.com) and [Express](http://expressjs.com) at the moment.

#### Firebase

Firebase is "backend as a service". They offer a free plan for production usage, have a look at it. If you like it, things are pretty easy here. You pay money and get a full-featured REST-like "backend" with built-in user management (See Firebase doc's for SimpleLogin). All you have to do is calling service methods.

#### Express

This is the DIY way. If you want to have full-control and a free way of doing things, this is the way to go. I am no Express master, so you better have a look at some Tutorials (http://expressjs-book.com/forums/topic/express-js-sessions-a-detailed-tutorial/)

If you don't like neither Firebase nor Express, have a look at other Backend-as-a-service offers. You could even use PHP. I would assume that one could say that this is the oldschool way of implementing user sessions :)